# Remove 'popular music' module from Facebook artist page

Tags: facebook, spotify, facebook-timeline

On the new Facebook Timelines for bands, they will show popular music by that artist. Except sometimes they get it wrong, and it seems impossible to remove!

Here is an example: The artist is called Sticky Fingers, but Facebook displays music by The Rolling Stoness: https://www.facebook.com/stickyfingersmusic

Does anyone know how to remove? Can someone from Facebook look into it? As you can imagine, it's a terrible experience for the artist.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming question - you'll have to contact Facebook support somehow to get it sorted.

Comment: Post the same question as a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

you can go to edit page > music and remove or change any catalogues that aren't the correct artist.

Comment: there is no 'music' section in the edit page area. can you show a screenshot? thanks